# jquery / Get only number after particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
href="something.do?something_id=-1&something=u_container_id=6445194287^something=70a6c7ca4f9d52001cb17e918110c72f";
href1="something.do?something=u_container_id=7757033893";
var id = href1.substr(href1.lastIndexOf("=") + 1 , href1.length);
```

This work good for href1 but not for href. I need to make a code which will get only container_id value. It can be 10 digits or less or more but will be only numbers

Comment: `var id = href1.match(/container_id=(\d+)/)[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with capturing group regex

```js
href = "something.do?something_id=-1&something=u_container_id=6445194287^something=70a6c7ca4f9d52001cb17e918110c72f";
href1 = "something.do?something=u_container_id=7757033893";
var id = href1.substr(href1.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, href1.length);

var id = href1.match(/container_id=(\d+)/)[1];

document.write(id);
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/yX7mB0/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find all these *container_id=* parts. Then you can extract the digits for each match:

```
href.match(/container_id=\d+/g).forEach(function(item){
    var id = item.split('=')[1];
    console.log(id);
});
```